# Replace mouse click for function key in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to setup Gimp to use a held key (e.g control or alt) to do the same as mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is no.
There are some mouse clicks in the tool boxes and editor dialogs which change parameters (like brush size) - these are mapped as "actions" inside GIMP and you can create keyboard shortcuts for them (including using the F keys) under `Edit->Preferences->Interface->Edit Keyboard Shortcuts...`

But probably that is not what you want - the main mouse button-click effect in GIMP is stroking the image with a paint tool - and that is wired in a different way inside the program: it can't be replaced by a keypress.

However, there are different painting devices that can be used that might serve your needs - a graphics tablet like those sold by Wacon provide a fundamentally different interface than mouse not just for GIMP, but for all drawing programs.

And  GIMP is somewhat a unique program that can actually make use of a MIDI controler
(like a MIDI foot controller) to control the pressure of the painting - so, if your problem is getting rid of the "click and hold"  action for painting with the mouse, a proper configured such peripheral could serve you.

That said, this question would be ontopic for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and is offtopic here - I hope someone can move both the question and this answer there.

Answer (score 0):

If GIMP does not allow such function. I have a suggestion, if you are using Ubuntu you can enable mouse control by numeric keypad as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html.en). After enabling mouse control by numeric keypad you must turn Num Lock ON and press the key 5 to simulate a mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I use is to rebind an unused key to left mouse button, through macro or some other method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).